# Trouble deploying Nestjs app on Vercel (Zeit)

Tags: github, nestjs, vercel

I have a github action set up to deploy a Nestjs app on Vercel, but it is giving me the following error:

`You defined 1 build that did not match any source files (please ensure they are NOT defined in .vercelignore):`

There is nothing after the `:` in the message - just that.

My `now.json` looks as follows:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/main.js",
      "use": "@now/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/main.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have been able to deploy the project before and just can't understand what has changed.

I must add that the error only happens when I try to deploy through the Git integration. It works as expected when I deploy from command line.

Comment: run locallly `npm run build` and check build folder that it is making the build right or not.

Comment: Seems to be making the right thing, can't see anything that's missing.

Comment: It only happens to when I do it through the Git integration, not when I deploy it from command line.

Comment: how you deploy through command line?

Comment: Just by running `now`.